# Python ¿como quitar espacios en blanco de un numero?

Tags: python, scraping, numberformat

Al hacer un scrap recibo esta informacion.

> ('CAMISETA BLANCO BLANCO', '16806474', '1 124.46', 'M')<

al hacer la insercción en la basde de datos, el  "1 124.46" es un dato erroneo por que no se considera un decimal ya que tiene un (espacio) dentro del numero.

Extraigo la información de esta variable:

> price_Product = product.find('span', attrs=['price product-price']).get_text()[:-5]<

como puedo solucionar mi problema sin que, si es posible añadir otro bucle mas (y me relentice aun mucho mas la extracción).
el varlor que necesito seria "1124.46" (el numero sin el espacio en el interior).

gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cual sería el valor correcto en el ejemplo?

Comment: Perdon, no me exprese del todo bien
el valor correcto seria sin el espacio entre medio del numero. "1124.46"

Comment: Añade al final de la expresión que extrae el número un `.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: al no ser una cadena de texto no me deja. Me pone como la cual es un float

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he podido solucionar con la biblioteca "RE"
con lo que queda asi:

<price_Product = re.sub(r'(\s)','',product.find('span', attrs=['price product-price']).get_text()[:-5])>

espero que no me muchos problemas de rendimiento.
Gracias por sus ayudas

Comment: Mejor implementa la sugerencia de abulafia, que es más simple y rápida.

Comment: como es que esa biblioteca magica si funciona contra algo que no es una cadena, y el replace (que al hacer un gettext seguro devolvio una cadena), no?